# Why do I get the output "[Function]"?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, javascript-objects

```
var Alex = new Person("Alex", "Burrows", 30, "Brown");

console.log(Alex.name);

function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
  this.name = function() {return "Hello"};
}
```

I'm expecting the console to output Hello, but I literally only get [Function] Returned. I'm using VS Code. Is it the fault of my code, or VS Studio?

If it's VS Studio's fault, what's a good IDE to use instead?

Comment: Most browsers will return `function() {return "Hello"}` instead of `[Function]`, which could save you from writing this question...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Alex.name`

```js
console.log(Alex.name())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(Alex.name);
```

here you're passing you reference to your function so that is the reason for the output being [Function].

try this instead:

```
console.log(Alex.name());
```

here you're calling the function so you'd be getting what the function is returning.